# Slow startup of fresh ZSH install in VS Code integrated terminal possibly Mac OSX wide

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have a fresh install of zsh and oh my zsh. i've updated the login shell as zsh and haven't changed the .zshrc file. I've updated the VS code settings file to: "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh".

On startup, not only is VS Code starting up slow, the terminal takes almost 10 seconds after to let me work in it and the little window on the right saying what shell i'm using flickers between bash and zsh about 8-12 times before settling in on zsh.

any ideas as to what's going on with it? when i switch back to bash, vsc startup and terminal is ready instantly.

Answer (score 1):

So after looking at my $PATH I noticed a dozen duplicate rbenv shims...so I removed those and it's fine now.